# Does the order of heroku buildpacks has an importance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, phantomjs, buildpack

I added several buildpacks in my heroku app :

```
➜  tennis-match git:(master) heroku buildpacks --app we-tennis-staging                                                                    
=== we-tennis-staging Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
2. http://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git
3. https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
4. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
5. --buildpack=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

but now I cannot push anymore to heroku :

```
-> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> PhantomJS app detected
remote: -----> Fetching PhantomJS 1.9.8 binaries at https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
remote: -----> Extracting PhantomJS 1.9.8 binaries to /tmp/build_d85248ffdc50138a22fb863a0367b5f2/vendor/phantomjs
remote: -----> exporting PATH and LIBRARY_PATH
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to we-tennis-staging.
```

Does the order of the buildpacks has any importance. Why is my app crashing ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you haven't set all the dependancies of the Buildpack - Some buildpacks require you to have specific settings in your app

Comment: can you be a little more specific ? I dont see which specific settings I need in my app here

Comment: Try setting Heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git --index 1 / and in your .buildpacks file set in your other buildpacks

Comment: It doesnt work, I still cant push on heroku. Where is my .buildpacks file ? I cant find it in my app...

Comment: It should be in the main app directory folder / you have to create the folder yourself - touch .buildpacks them there